# WebSphere Message Broker - how to send a PCF message

Tags: ibm-mq, broker

We need to issue some MQ commands from a MB flow.
The way to go is to send a PCF command, but I dont know how to create it.
Any pointers ?
Sebastian.

Answer (score 2):

To issue commands to an MQ Queue Manager via PCF messages you can look at the examples in  /opt/mqm/samp/pcf/samples on *nix or where ever you have installed MQ. (On Windows try "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\tools\pcf\samples").

To issue the commands 'from' broker you can use a Java compute node and use methods in the supplied Java package com.ibm.mq, for example sending a query to find out what queues are defined on a queue manager:

```
import com.ibm.mq.headers.pcf.PCFMessageAgent;
import com.ibm.mq.headers.pcf.PCFMessage;
import com.ibm.mq.constants.MQConstants;

try
{
    // local queue manager
    String queueManager = "QMGR_broker"; // local queue manager name 
    PCFMessageAgent agent = new PCFMessageAgent(queueManager);

    // remote queue manager
    String host = "localhost"; // host name of the queue manager machine
    int port = 1414; // default queue manager tcp listener port
    String channel = "SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN";//Default channel
    PCFMessageAgent agent = new PCFMessageAgent(host, port, channel);

    // Create the PCF message type for the inquire.
    PCFMessage pcfCmd = new PCFMessage(MQConstants.MQCMD_INQUIRE_Q_NAMES);
    // Queue name = wildcard.
    pcfCmd.addParameter(MQConstants.MQCA_Q_NAME, "*");
    // Queue type = ALL.
    pcfCmd.addParameter(MQConstants.MQIA_Q_TYPE, MQConstants.MQQT_ALL);

    // Execute the command. The returned object is an array of PCF messages.
    PCFMessage[] pcfResponse = pcfCM.agent.send(pcfCmd);

    // e.g. extract the queue names from the response object
    String[] names = (String[])pcfResponse[0].getParameterValue(MQConstants.MQCACF_Q_NAMES);
}
```

Alternatively you can put the PCF messages on the MQ queue (SYSTEM.ADMIN.COMMAND.QUEUE if you're on anything but z/OS) that the queue manager is listening for events on. You will then also need to define a 'reply to' queue in your message. You can do this from broker with an MQOutput node.

However that means you need to know the [exact format of the PCF message](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv6/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.amqzag.doc%2Ffa11570_.htm) that you want to send and what it's reply will look like, I think it is much easier to use the provided Java examples to do the message processing and formatting for you.